# Passing data from table to Modal Table

Tags: modal-dialog

I have two tables for my inventory first is the Item List then the Item Info

I bind the Item List to a HTML Table the add a button for each row the purpose of the button is to show the Item Info or table via modal

I have already done the table and modal design but i cant get or pass the Item ID for my Item List to my modal

can  anyone help me i'm kind a new in HTML (noob hir :3)

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
    <th class="text-center">Particular</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody class="searchable">
  <% List<Inventory.MODEL.adminView>x = new List
    <Inventory.MODEL.adminView>(); Inventory.BAL.ItemBAL z = new Inventory.BAL.ItemBAL(); x = z.getAdminView().ToList(); foreach (var item in x) {%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%=i tem.ID %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%=i tem.Particulars %>
        </td>
        <%}%>
          <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#Modal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info-sm" onclick="myFunction()"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span></a>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <%} %>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>
<div id="Modal" class="modal fade">

  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Item Inventory</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
              <th class="text-center">Total Quantity</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <% iteminvents(); %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

that's my code, anyone can advice or can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `this` in `myFunction()` as argument , As `myFunction(this)`

and inside function you can get ItemId as below. I have used jquery here.

```
function myFunction(sender)
{
  var CurrentRow=$(sender).closest("tr");

  var ItemId=$("td:eq(0)",$(CurrentRow)).html();  // Can Trim also if needed


}
```

Comment: thank you for the script but im still having a problem in displaying it to my modal

Comment: Which problem? are you able to get the ItemId now?

Comment: i already got it tnx for the script and for your time sir really appreciate it :))